# 10x performance difference between mysqli_query and bind_param ( PHP 7)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, bindparam

I was trying to insert something to my database and I decided to do it with two different ways to see query performances.

I used 
(end_microtime - starting_microtime) way to see what's happening.

Bind param code:

```
<?php
timer_start = microtime(TRUE);


$db = @new mysqli('localhost','root','','database');
$username = "username";
$email= "test@html.com";
$password = "123456789";

 $query = "INSERT INTO users (username,email,password) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);

$stmt->bind_param("sss", $username, $email, $password);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();

$timer_end = microtime(TRUE);  
echo($timer_end - $timer_start);  

?>
```

result: ~ 0.090020895004272

mysqli_query code (there was a syntax error before I changed it now)

```
<?php
$timer_start = microtime(TRUE);


$db = @new mysqli('localhost','root','','database');
$username = "username";
$email= "asdf@ghj.com";
$password = "123456789";

$query = "INSERT INTO users (username,email,password) 
                   VALUES  ('$username','$email','$password')";
mysqli_query($db,$query);

$timer_end = microtime(TRUE);  
echo($timer_end - $timer_start);

?>
```

result = ~ 0.00070500373840332

question is : Why is this happening?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Because the connector has to process the bindings and determine which variables need to be quoted, escaped, and sanitized. The straight query is a blind insert so does not need to be processed, but is also wide open for SQL injection. So do you want to be fast or safe?

Comment: In your second example you are not quoting the values. And are not closing the connection.

Comment: @aynber That's a good answer. Thank you. But i want to ask  what happens if 1000 concurrent users try to enter something to database?

Comment: @aynber these variables are never be quoted, escaped, and sanitized, so your assumptions are plainly wrong. And moreover it doesn't explain such a big difference.

Comment: @gre_gor you can make it an answer as it explains everything (the quoting part)

Comment: @YourCommonSense I think you mean that they aren't quoted in the second example? You're correct, they aren't, so the query would fail.

Comment: @aynber I mean your ideas on how does prepared statement process its data, which are not even near to reality.

Comment: I retract my statement, then. It just seemed logical to me. *shrug*

Comment: @aynber the bound data never gets quoted or escaped. it's just sent apart from the query on the second call. And it is sent intact, as is.

Comment: It's also worth noting that in a situation where the same query might need to be run many times, `bind_param` can be run only once, and then all you need to do is update the bound variable before each execute, which should be quite fast. Probably faster than `query` as well, although I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between plain query and a prepared statement always exists, because for the latter you need **two round-trips** to the database, one to prepare the query and one to execute.

But nevertheless you don't have to consider prepared statements to be 2 times slower, because **the query execution process involves much more operations than just a round-trip to a server**, most of which are common for both methods and involve A LOT more time (storing the data on a hard disk for example).

And of course there is no such big difference like 10x. In your case it's just because **the second query never gets executed** due to silly syntax error.

Regarding your results for PDO, it is because by default PDO just fake prepared statements, processing the bound data by itself and then sending the regular query. While whatever alleged difference between .0002 and .0009 should not impress you too much because it all fits into measurement error.